# VBA Run time error '424' Object Required issue

Tags: vba, excel, dir

I'm trying to pass two sheets to a different subroutine in Excel VBA to make some manipulations to those sheets.  Ultimately, I'm trying to combine data from multiple sheets and delete all of the duplicate data found in each list.  I'm defining as an object:

```
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
```

Then I'm just trying to a function:

```
    Call ThisSubroutine(wb1.Sheets("Sheetnumber1"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet2"))
```

And I'm getting a run-time error '424' Object Required dialog box.  I'm sure there is an obvious solution here, but I'm overlooking something.  The sub is written:

```
Sub ThisSubroutine(Sourcefile As Worksheet, Targetfile As Worksheet)
```

On request, I'm adding the whole code:

```
Sub MergeDuplicates(ByVal DuplicateFilename As String) 'used ByVal because I was getting a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error; don't know why this happens with Dir function, as it should be passing a string, but this seems to fix it, at least as far as compiling the CheckDuplicates Sub
    'This one is a bit tricky, but I think the best way to do this is:
    'open the original and the duplicate copy (find partial string matches and open both files)
    Pathname = "\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Database Company Files\" 'for now... everything stays in my U drive
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(Pathname & DuplicateFilename)
    Dim Partialname As String
    File = Dir(Pathname)
    Partialname = Left(DuplicateFilename, 4)
    Do While File <> ""
        If StrComp(Left(File, 4), Partialname) = 0 Then
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & File)
        End If
        File = Dir()
    Loop

    'Create a new workbook, creates new sheets and name them
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    For i = 1 To 6
        newWB.Worksheets.Add After:=newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next i

    'copy the contents of both workbooks into the new one keeping everything on the appropriate sheets
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("General Information"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet2"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Markets"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet3"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Chemistries"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet4"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Processing Capabilities"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet5"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Equipment List"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet6")) 'Wrong, should not be using this function here
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Analytical & QC"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet7"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Utilities"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet8"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Stock Chemicals"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet9"))

    newWB.Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "General Information"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Markets"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Chemistries"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Name = "Processing Capabilities"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet6").Name = "Equipment List"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet7").Name = "Analytical & QC"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet8").Name = "Utilities"
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet9").Name = "Stock Chemicals"

    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("General Information"), newWB.Sheets("General Information"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Markets"), newWB.Sheets("Markets"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Chemistries"), newWB.Sheets("Chemistries"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Processing Capabilities"), newWB.Sheets("Processing Capabilities"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Equipment List"), newWB.Sheets("Equipment List")) 'Wrong.... should not be using this function for this purpose
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Analytical & QC"), newWB.Sheets("Analytical & QC"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Utilities"), newWB.Sheets("Utilities"))
    Call AddToNewTMWB(wb2.Sheets("Stock Chemicals"), newWB.Sheets("Stock Chemicals"))

    'use excel's built in "remove duplicates" functions on each list
    Sheet3.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet3.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet4.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet4.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet4.Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet5.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet5.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    'This is tricky.... not sure how to handle because there might be minor changes; maybe just don't include it at all...?
    Sheet6.Range("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), _
        Header:=xlYes
    Sheet7.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet7.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet8.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet8.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet9.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheet9.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    'for general information and the equipment list, this is going to be a bit trickier, because the duplicates
        'on the equipment list require matching for all 20-some-odd rows and the general information may be actual updates so
        'how can I decide what information to update?

    'save the old workbooks as "Company Name & City & Date & Old" and "Company Name & City & Date & Duplicate" in a different folder!!!!!
    wb1.SaveAs filename:="\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Duplicate Files\" & DuplicateFilename
    wb2.SaveAs filename:="\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Duplicate Files\" & "Merge " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy") & " " & File

    'save the newly created workbook as "Company Name & City" in \\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Database Company Files\
    newWB.SaveAs filename:=Pathname & File

    'Delete the old files from the "TM Database Company Files" folder

End Sub

Sub CopyToNewTMWB(SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim numRows As Integer, numCols As Integer
    Dim ActiveRangeOld As Range, ActiveRangeNew As Range

    'count cells to define active range
    numRows = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    numCols = SourceSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set ActiveRangeOld = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(numRows, numCols)) 'set active range equal to appropriate size

    Set ActiveRangeNew = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(numRows, numCols)) 'choose range on new worksheet of same size as above
    ActiveRangeNew.Value = ActiveRangeOld.Value 'set the new range values equal to the old ones without having to select any cells

End Sub

Sub AddToNewTMWB(ByVal SourceSheet As Worksheet, ByVal TargetSheet As Worksheet) 'slightly different, just copies the cells to the first unused location

    Dim numRows As Integer, numCols As Integer
    Dim ActiveRangeOld As Range, ActiveRangeNew As Range

    'count cells to define active range
    numRows1 = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    numRows2 = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    numRowTarget1 = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    numRowTarget2 = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'write duplicates at end of existing list for new worksheet
    Set ActiveRangeOld = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(numRows1, 1)) 'set active range equal to appropriate size in first column
    Set ActiveRangeNew = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(numRowTarget1 + 1, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(numRowTarget1 + numRows1 + 1, 1)) 'choose range on new worksheet of same size as above
    ActiveRangeNew.Value = ActiveRangeOld.Value 'set the new range values equal to the old ones without having to select any cells
    'repeat for 2nd column
    Set ActiveRangeOld = SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(1, 2), SourceSheet.Cells(numRows1, 2)) 'set active range equal to appropriate size in first column
    Set ActiveRangeNew = TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(numRowTarget1 + 1, 2), TargetSheet.Cells(numRowTarget1 + numRows1 + 1, 2)) 'choose range on new worksheet of same size as above
    ActiveRangeNew.Value = ActiveRangeOld.Value 'set the new range values equal to the old ones without having to select any cells

End Sub
```

Comment: The sheets exist under those exact names in the associated workbooks?

Comment: Yes I believe so.  Let me check, since I'm generating a new workbook, I'm just assuming the names there is "Sheet2"

Comment: Yes, those are the exact names

Comment: Can you post all of your code? On which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: Error is on the line: Call ThisSubroutine(wb1.Sheets("Sheetnumber1"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet2"))

Comment: You need to debug your code - when it errors, hover the mouse over the various objects on that line of code and see what you get.  Or use the Locals window.

Comment: a) After finding wb2 yo don't appear to do anything to it except saveas.  b)What is the parent workbook that you are trying to remove duplicates from Sheet3:Sheet9?

Answer (score 0):

See if you work through the modifications and comments on this rewrite. I've defined worksheet and cell range parentage to their respective workbook or worksheet. All vars are explicitly declared (no variants or objects unless needed).

```
Sub MergeDuplicates(DuplicateFilename As String)
    'This one is a bit tricky, but I think the best way to do this is:
    'open the original and the duplicate copy (find partial string matches and open both files)
    Dim fn As String, pn As String, pfn As String, vVALs As Variant
    Dim w As Long, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, newWB As Workbook

    pn = "\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Database Company Files\" 'for now... everything stays in my U drive
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(pn & DuplicateFilename)
    fn = Dir(pn)
    pfn = Left(DuplicateFilename, 4)

    Do While CBool(Len(fn))
        If StrComp(Left(fn, Len(pfn)), pfn, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then  'vbTextCompare to remove case sensitive
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(pn & fn)
            Exit Do  '<no sense continuing if you have what you wa
        End If
        fn = Dir()
    Loop

    'Create a new workbook, creates new sheets and name them
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        Do While .Worksheets.Count < 9  'who says every new workbook has three worksheets? Mine has one.
            .Worksheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Loop
    End With

    'copy the contents of both workbooks into the new one keeping everything on the appropriate sheets
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("General Information"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet2"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Markets"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet3"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Chemistries"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet4"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Processing Capabilities"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet5"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Equipment List"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet6")) 'Wrong, should not be using this function here
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Analytical & QC"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet7"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Utilities"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet8"))
    Call CopyToNewTMWB(wb1.Sheets("Stock Chemicals"), newWB.Sheets("Sheet9"))

    'new worksheet renaming moved to CopyToNewTMWB

    'not sure what the parent workbook is... I'm guessing hte newly added one.
    With newWB
    'use excel's built in "remove duplicates" functions on each list
        vVALs = Array("General Information", "Markets", "Chemistries", _
                       "Processing Capabilities", "Analytical & QC", _
                       "Utilities", "Stock Chemicals")
        For w = LBound(vVALs) To UBound(vVALs)
            With .Worksheets(vVALs(w))
                .Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
                .Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            End With
        Next w
        vVALs = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
        'leave the brackets surrounding (vVALs) in hte next statement. They are important.
        With Worksheets("Equipment List")  '<-Sheet6
            .Range("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(vVALs), Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

    'for general information and the equipment list, this is going to be a bit trickier, because the duplicates
        'on the equipment list require matching for all 20-some-odd rows and the general information may be actual updates so
        'how can I decide what information to update?

    'save the old workbooks as "Company Name & City & Date & Old" and "Company Name & City & Date & Duplicate" in a different folder!!!!!
    wb1.SaveAs Filename:="\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Duplicate Files\" & DuplicateFilename

    'Is this the only thing that wb2 is used for? What if it was never found?
    On Error Resume Next
    wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Duplicate Files\" & "Merge " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy") & " " & fn

    'save the newly created workbook as "Company Name & City" in \\SRVWIN0791\Daniel_Armstrong$\TM Database Company Files\
    newWB.SaveAs Filename:=pn & fn

    'Delete the old files from the "TM Database Company Files" folder

End Sub

Sub CopyToNewTMWB(SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Long
    Dim ActiveRangeOld As Range, ActiveRangeNew As Range

    'count cells to define active range
    With SourceSheet
        numRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        numCols = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set ActiveRangeOld = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(numRows, numCols)) 'set active range equal to appropriate size
    End With

    With TargetSheet
        Set ActiveRangeNew = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(numRows, numCols)) 'choose range on new worksheet of same size as above
        .Name = SourceSheet.Name
    End With

    ActiveRangeNew = ActiveRangeOld.Value 'set the new range values equal to the old ones without having to select any cells

End Sub
```

Note that I moved the new worksheet renaming to the CopyToNewTMWB routine. Since you had both the old and new and needed to synch their names, this seemed an appropriate way to save some code lines.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on writing that out a bit more cleanly.  Didn't occur to me to use the sheets as items in an array.  I'll try this new one and see if the Run-time error is still a problem.

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting a different error after declaring all of the variables explicitly (same line of Call CopToNewTMWB).  Never seen this one before: Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error

Comment: Once you get this working to some degree of satisfaction, turning off the [Application.ScreenUpdating property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) and the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) should get it running pretty quick. Remember to turn them back on before leaving the sub, perhaps with error control.

Comment: There were a few problems with my methods, notably the array of Worksheet [.CodeName properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) (I was *sure* that I had used that previously. The above mods run through on my full test environment with the exception of hte Save/Save As. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish and tbh, it looks like you might be trying to overwrite one the the open files before it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone.  I used to Locals window to check the properties of my workbook variables and realized that wb1 had no assignment.  Instead of finding the original file in the Do loop at the top, I was just finding the duplicate file again and reassigning it to wb2.  Stupid mistake, should've picked up on that much sooner.  I changed the If statement in that loop to:

```
    Do While File <> ""
        If StrComp(Left(File, 4), Partialname) = 0 And StrComp(File, DuplicateFilename) <> 0 Then 'partially matching filenames will enter this if statement, but not exact matches. Can't have files with the exact same name in the same folder anyway, so this will also pick up "filename" matched with "filename(1)", but will not reassign wb2 when it finds "filename"
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & File)
            wb2found = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        File = Dir()
    Loop
```

Moral: 424 Object Required errors are exactly that.